# Find all rows, that have at least n values in common with a specific item

Tags: sql, sql-server, ado.net

I have a table, sort of like this:

```
Items
-----------
    ID Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4 Value5 Value6
    1  345895 435234 342534 678767 5455   423555
    2  3245   549238 230944 923948 234488 234997
    3  490458 49349  234234 87810  903481 3940102
    4  849545 435234 67678  98741  99084  978897
```

How would I write a query, that finds all the items, that have at least 3 values (just an example, could be more than 3) in common with a specific item i.e. I have an item

```
    345895 435234 67678 98741 5455 423555
```

and running this query would give me

```
 1  345895 435234 342534 678767 5455   423555
 4  849545 435234 67678  98741  99084  978897
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CASE` statements in the `WHERE` clause in order to calculate the number of matches:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM Items AS i
CROSS JOIN ( VALUES ( 345895, 435234, 67678, 98741, 5455, 423555) ) AS Item(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6)
WHERE (CASE WHEN i.Value1 = Item.v1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
            (CASE WHEN i.Value2 = Item.v2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
            (CASE WHEN i.Value3 = Item.v3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
            (CASE WHEN i.Value4 = Item.v4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
            (CASE WHEN i.Value5 = Item.v5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
            (CASE WHEN i.Value6 = Item.v6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 3
```

Comment: This is not working, some data that has more than 3 numbers are not returned. I had a similar answer but i deleted it and posted a new one. For this logic to work, null values must be returned.

Comment: Can you give me a concrete example where my query does not work?

Comment: Column value1 has this values: 345895,3245,490458,849545, all 4 values in this case, have values that have a length of character larger than 3. Your query is returning only 2 of those.

Comment: Example in this question is not consistent with demanded logic.

Comment: @Dn24Z I'm afraid you have misunderstood the requirements of the OP: The OP pertains to matching of at least three values between records of the `Items` table and a *specific* item. There is no reference regarding field character length.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

```
; with sub as(
select 345895 as mynum
union all select 435234
union all select 67678
union all select 98741
union all select 5455
union all select 423555
)
select i.*
from items i
join
    (
        select x.id
        from(
                select id, value1 as val from items union all
                select id, value2 from items union all
                select id, value3 from items union all
                select id, value4 from items union all
                select id, value5 from items union all
                select id, value6 from items
                ) x join sub s on x.val = s.mynum
        group by x.id
        having count(*) >= 3
    ) x on x.id = i.id
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1dff3/2/0